# Import sklearn error DLL load failed. How to make it right?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[image]

I wrote just `import sklearn`. What's wrong?

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not image. Also, please translate the Russian message. Also, please tell us what versions of Python, which install (Anaconda? Canopy?), sklearn and Windows you're on. Does your Python install work correctly? Can you import other packages? Did you configure PYTHONPATH? How did you install sklearn? (pip? conda install? which versions) etc.

Comment: Can you also provide Windows version as well?